# Read variable inside double bracket in Helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I need read a field `file` from `values.yml` for a configMap setup, it's my template:

```
{{- if .Values.configMap.enabled }}
{{- range .Values.configMapMount }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
data:
  {{ .file }}: {{ $.Files.Get "files/{{ .file }}" | printf "%s" | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Obviously this template doesn't work...there is a way to read `{{ .file }}` inside `"files/{{ .file }}"` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest template [*actions*](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template@go1.20#hdr-Actions). Use a [*variable*](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template@go1.20#hdr-Variables) instead.

Something like this:

```yaml
{{- if .Values.configMap.enabled }}
{{- range .Values.configMapMount }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
data:
  {{- $f := printf "files/%s" .file }}
  {{ .file }}: {{ $.Files.Get $f | printf "%s" | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/pRd5WNc10Zt

Comment: Thanks, it works! But the result of template is https://imgur.com/zQUGFOJ why `.file` isn't in a new line and indent?

Comment: @hellb0y77 Try removing the `-` on the right side of the variable action. Answer updated.